# Finding files that does not have a particular owner OR group

Tags: find

I'd like to use GNU `find` to find sub-directories and files under the current path that *either* does not have the particular user OR the particular group.

```
find . -not -user USERXXX -or -not -group GROUPYYY
```

seems not working.

I can tell that because collecting all unique ownership values with `-exec`

```
find . -not -user USERXXX -or -not -group GROUPYYY -exec stat -f '%Su:%Sg' '{}' \; | sort -u
```

will miss

```
root:staff
root:GROUPYYY
```

Any idea why? It seems the user `USERXXX` is seen by `find` as `root` somehow?

- GNU find 4.9.0.

```
gfind --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.9.0
Packaged by Homebrew
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

OS: macOS 14.3.2